# How to retrieve the distinct domains of a compound domain from DQS using SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, data-quality-services

MS Data Quality Services (DQS) has a concept of Compound Domains, which lets you turn say "'99 Chevy Maliboo" into {year:1999, brand:Chevrolet, model:Malibu}

SSIS has a "DQS Cleansing" component. It only seems to let you retrieve one column back, not the distinct fields of the compound domain. Is there a way to do this?

If not, is there a reasonably simple way to do this with a Script Component?

Version info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081

Installed Version: IDE Standard

Visual C# 2013   06154-004-0430007-02752
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.50730.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 12.0.2430.0
```